# Is it possible to detect if the call is being transferred on FreeSWITCH?

Tags: lua, detect, transfer, freeswitch

I want to detect if the call is being transferred in FreeSWITCH.

For e.g If I am now calling someone and that someone transfers me to an other person, I want to know during the call if a transfer happens.

I wonder if there is in Freeswitch an event that fires upon call transfer or is there a channel variable or should I test the transfer time?

Any idea how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: this should be asked on freeswitch.org, not here...

Comment: Run full sip trace on FS and make a call transfer and see if there is any change in sip trace to that particular call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its possible to detect transfer in FreeSWITCH like user A call user B ,user B answer the call,user B transfer the call to c then following things happen:

- Phone B sends a REFER message to Phone A. The message contains the
  following information:

  ```
  • Refer-To: C

  • Referred-By: B
  ```
- The message indicates that Phone A should send an INVITE request to
  Phone C.